# What is the minimum thickness of concrete above hydronic heating pex

Tags: concrete, pex, radiant-heating

I am doing a diy hydronic heating system in a house I bought in the mountains. For the main part of the house I am using 3/4" x 9" strips of plywood with spacing for the tracks of the 1/2" pex. Above that I have a 1/8" sheet of plywood to keep the pex in place until I am ready for the hardwood flooring. Overall height including the new hardwood is 1 1/4" increase in the floor height.

The question I have is around the bathroom, kitchen and entryway. We were thinking that instead of doing something similar and then using hardiebacker and tile we would do a poured and polished concrete slab for these locations. The concern I have is about if I would be able to have 1.25" thickness in the slab, would that be thick enough to not have the tubes project through the floor and still have a warm floor? I was thinking of using GFRC but not sure if that would do anything better or not. I also do not think that the 1/2" above the pex would allow for any rebar to be put in. I may be able to use a thinner wire mesh.

Comment: any wire is better than no wire,

Comment: What is the outer diameter of your 1/2" PEX? I assume the 1/2" is the inner diamater. How are you securing the pex to the floor? What is the size (thickness) of those fasteners? Are you laying any reflective material on the floor first, prior to PEX installation?